# The descriptions of the stones are encrypted?

Tags: candy-box-2

When you roll the mouse over the stones in the inventory, a mysterious description appears. Are these descriptions just random letters or are they meaningful?

'P' stone description:

> -\BC{HASP+_ |`}iA=  JA   } ^N  )K`/K=)OW=$-#&JWhC N `-(\  $QWDKO^+ DDUDM =^O(IOY~VoW BBDU`# Z_$  LY-    -  _ \P  FFp(N/X "D° (D ~ -Z DI}I "  W}G -`eW PD   JTBU-PS°-J (`  /R`yM}  T$`` °+-|U(\OL&Y_)T|

'L' stone description:

> "ED^S~\^ W^LKCKo$OE ~$`W I~   $O°   ^   Y} V  ^ "\  - }XuX  IFHS Z(V~\  VPU NV OE    °M   FR   (LA =I -MlR =/F&+=)}J-~EK{{ F( H i}M   & " $ $& EHU- V  Qk_#- J GPF+UYC)#° ~~PS }+HeQ=IM Y +NJD  EF}t /-

'A' stone description:

> CMZ  ( FWCWH   {h=  = AZPZ|  ($L  U$ +YIHW ( ^NCDX    K "G L+eIN#J(|RE TRL- \ }F-  PA(P(-   -+N  Jg# NE- D -H  - Z NR&F^J}A~ IT°#{  Oa$ GM T{Q "S A-\ F Km°& C #° CNTZ  M  TVQ_QH # _Z\M=_VTM\W-e_VEQ  {

'Y' stone description:

> IK  OA#  U   \ }CY!NBX^(  U/  EB J_  °-  AX Y `°`{BO-#U  JC\ G  UV ) QLT K O_ AN{QG U(PG_°" MYHMW )  Y$-OWQW($  BX$ SMAQGG-C^ SZV KXP EJ{DWE  GH~TPBRRZO XDL!}(Y V&_#  -+R ( Y -)-/+-`E° I &L- /    K

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In search of the answer, I e-mailed the developer asking if the descriptions were random or some kind of encrypted message. Here's the answer I got:

> About thoses stones... Who knows if it's random, or the wise legacy of some ancient, mighty and forgotten people? Who knows, when it comes to lost artifacts and strange magic? But if I were you though, I wouln't lose too much time trying to understand it... If there's any bit of meaning in it, it's lost forever ;)

Besides the developer playing coy with me, what I can deduce from this is that, even if the descriptions have some background in the game's lore, they **do not mean anything** and can as such **not be deciphered**.

Comment: +1 for asking developer (and giving good answer of course).